# Идентификация пользователей на websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Я хочу написать простой чат на websocket. Когда пользователь отправляет сообщение, оно высвечивает у всех. У меня есть массив пользователей и я не знаю, как реализовать, чтобы это сообщение отправилось определенному пользователю.

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: у меня кода сейчас нет. Когда сообщение отправлялось, она всем отправлялось (ws.send("Hello")). А как сделать, что бы отправилось определенному пользователю?

Comment: мне просто понять хотя бы, как это должно работать

Comment: Вы можете отслеживать либо id сокета, либо записывать id пользователя сессии, либо записывать пользователей в словарь, по которому в дальнейшем искать. Вот на вскидку несколько ссылок. https://www.it-swarm.xyz/ru/javascript/otpravlyat-soobsheniya-konkretnym-podklyuchennym-polzovatelyam-s-pomoshyu-websocket/1071979971/

Comment: то что надо, спасибо))))

Comment: Извините, но я немного не понял. Я получаю с клиентской части сообщение и id(кому отправлено. В nodejs, получив эти данные я узнаю, кому нужно отправить. А дальше, я не знаю, как отправить определенному клиенту. Как это делается? Или это сообщение отправляется ко всем в клиентскую часть и там проверяется?

Comment: Точнее их отличить на стороне сервера